# QML RTSP Stream from a network camera

Tags: qt, qml, rtsp, qt5.10

I have a question about the RTSP Stream. How can I display a RTSP Stream from a netwok camera in qml?

the settings:

- Qt5.10
- Camera: LunaIP L-DA-5203-V2
- OS: Windows 7

Things I have tested:

QML: [Camera](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html), [MediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html), [VideoOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html)

Until now I didn't found any things how I can solve it in QML?

Comment: it looks that QML doesn't support rtsp: [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37999)

Comment: @folibis thanks, is there another possibilty to display the stream of a webcam withour rtsp?

Comment: may be some VCL plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 ways, which worked for me:**

**1.)** In my `form.ui.qml` I'm using the `MediaPlayer` and the `VideoOutput` components

```
    MediaPlayer {
        id: videoPlayer
        source: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
        muted: true
        autoPlay: true
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: camera1
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        source: videoPlayer
    }
```

**2.)** OR I'm using the `Video` compoennt in  my `form.ui.qml` as follow

```
    Video {
        id: cam1Stream
        x: 49
        y: 91
        width: 505
        height: 336
        source: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
        autoPlay: true
        opacity: 1.0
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
        muted: false
    }
```